# How can I return the array to another class?

Tags: java, android

I have a class one,and this class will transmit some data to class two, but now I have a class three, and it must use the class two's data. How can I do?

---

This is the code that get json from my server:

```
private void sendRequestWithHttpClient(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("");
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    if(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){
                        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                        String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity,"utf-8");
                        parseJSON(response);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void parseJSON(String jsonData) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);
            String[] a = new String[jsonArray.length()];
            String[] b = new String[jsonArray.length()];
            for (int i=0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                String main = jsonObject.getString("main");
                a[i] = title;
                b[i] = main;
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I must use this data to update my list now,but I can not found some methods to solve it.

```
private List<String> getData() {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        data.add("");
    }
    return data;
}
```

thanks for help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array like this

```
String[] humza = new String[0];
```

and then pass to intent like this

```
intent.putExtra("humza",humza);
```